# Relating Multiple Tables to One Table [SQL - Oracle 12c]

Tags: sql, oracle12c

I'll try my best to pose this as a question, and not a "write my script" request- but finding it hard to phrase without using the working example.

To start, here's a relational diagram of what I'm working with;

[image]

**TABLE 1 - TABLE 2 are scalable, i.e there is a TABLE 4 - TABLE 5, TABLE  -... etc, it's Tables, A/B/C that are constant.

Essentially, what I'm trying to do with this structure is match a certain value that only exists in TABLE 1 or 2 to TABLE C, where I'll pass that value to TABLE 1 or 2 and return the TABLE C value.

```
SELECT
TABLEC.CUSTOMID
FROM TABLE1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.TABLE2ENTITYKEY = TABLE2.ENTITYKEY 
INNER JOIN TABLEA ON TABLEA.ENTITYKEY = TABLE2.TABLEAENTITYKEY 
INNER JOIN TABLEB ON TABLEB.ENTITYKEY = TABLEA.TABLEBENTITYKEY 
INNER JOIN TABLEC ON TABLEC.ENTITYKEY = TABLEB.TABLECENTITYKEY 
WHERE TABLE1.USERENTITYKEY = /*ENTER_VALUE*/
```

OR

```
SELECT
TABLEC.CUSTOMID
FROM TABLE3
INNER JOIN TABLE4 ON TABLE3.TABLE4ENTITYKEY = TABLE4.ENTITYKEY 
INNER JOIN TABLEA ON TABLEA.ENTITYKEY = TABLE4.TABLEAENTITYKEY 
INNER JOIN TABLEB ON TABLEB.ENTITYKEY = TABLEA.TABLEBENTITYKEY 
INNER JOIN TABLEC ON TABLEC.ENTITYKEY = TABLEB.TABLECENTITYKEY 
WHERE TABLE3.USERENTITYKEY = /*ENTER_VALUE*/
```

Both of these work, and will work for my Tables 5/6, 7/8 etc - but that leaves me with multiple queries.
What I'd like to do is 'combine' these queries into one, where I'll pass my value to Tables 1/3/5 etc and return any values from C that link back to any of the source tables - it's not important that I know which source table the value in C links too, it's only important that it links to one of them.

Does anyone have any suggestions or examples I can use to see how this kind of script is formatted? I have played around with some things - but my SQL isn't that strong, so it's futile so far.

Thanks in advance, please comment if more information is required - and sorry in advance if the question is poorly asked!

-L

Answer (score 0):

Not a full solution - but currently tying the two above queries together using UNION.